# Route::when() not working with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this basic code:

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
Route::when('admin/*', 'admin-auth');
Route::filter('admin-auth',function(){
if(!Auth::user())
        return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

Apparently, when I run my application, Laravel 4 routing could not run the authentication check.

Seems to me that they revamped the "pattern" catching that was in Laravel 3 for Laravel 4.

Comment: Is your filter in app/filters.php file?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Route::when('admin*', 'admin-auth');
```

Instead of:

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'admin-auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your route like this..

```
Route::when('admin/*', ['before' => 'admin-auth', 'uses' => 'adminController@indexAction']);
```

This will work when doing Route::get/post not sure about using when .. just fyi.

Comment: Use [] for array's if your php version is 5.4. If not use Route::when('admin/*', array('before' => 'admin-auth', 'uses' => 'adminController@indexAction'));

Answer (score 0):

You have to write you Route::when() filter in the app/filters.php
Just move the Route::when('admin*', 'auth') to the app/filters.php and the path admin will require login

Just assumed that plain login function was what you where looking for, so just used laravel auth filter.